# filter ip adress of docker container via ansible

Tags: docker, ansible, dockerpy

I'm trying to get an ip adress from an docker container w/ ansible-module docker_container_info.
Following is my suspection how it would be get excluded from the result.

```
  - name: Get infos on container
    docker_container_info:
      name: nextcloud-db
    register: result_container
  - name: Dump grep matching interfaces from ansible_interfaces
    set_fact:
       interfaces_list: "{{ result_container | select('match', '^IPAddress') }}"
  - debug:
      var: result_container
  - debug:
      var: interfaces_list
```

while trying this i get this error

```
TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "interfaces_list": "<generator object select_or_reject at 0x7f2bb30d55a0>"
}
```

How do i extract the ip address from this result else?
The goal is to create an variable that i can use later to dump an database and import it to another docker container.

Answer (score 0):

The below should works for me:

```
- hosts: localhost
  sudo: yes

  tasks: 
    - name: Get infos on container
      docker_container_info:
        name: <some_name>
      register: result
    
    - debug:
        var: result | json_query('container.NetworkSettings.[IPAddress]')
```

play output:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Get infos on container] **********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "result | json_query('container.NetworkSettings.[IPAddress]')": [
        "172.17.0.2"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: does not give me the expected result... "interfaces_list": "<generator object select_or_reject at 0x7fa88d10b6e0>"